# Guarantee only one timerTasks with threads in service

Tags: android, android-service, timertask

My Android application has a service, that will be created at timer task with specified interval. The task should check out webservice by async task, if the Internet is enabled, send some informations, otherwise it should wait (for example, 5 seconds) and check connection again.

**My problem is: how to prevent creating tasks while timertask is waiting?**

**I wish that at any time there is only one task working.**

My code:

```
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 10000); //creating tasks in service

class MyTask extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
    if (!isLocked) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {@Override
            public void run() {
                isLocked = true;
                if (!isInternet) {
                    do {
                        Log.v("TestService", "Waiting...");
                        SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                        isInternet = getInternetConn();
                    } while (!isInternet);
                } else {
                    //do work
                }
                isLocked = false;
            }).run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow this process, which i have used for getting GCM_Registration id, same as you can use it check your internet connection.

which works like : in `onStartCommand()`, `mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg)`; starts a asynctask which check does we have `GCM-ID` if yes we stop the service and if no, then we again check for `GCM-ID` by asynctask.

```
package com.urbanft.utils;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.urbanft.app.GlobalPreference;

public class GCMIdFetchService extends Service {

    private final String SENDER_ID = "916449540455";
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging mGoogleCloudMessaging;
    private String mRegisterationId;    

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            new GCMIdFetchSearviceTask().execute("");
        }
    }

    protected void initialization() {
        mGoogleCloudMessaging = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    class GCMIdFetchSearviceTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            getGCMID();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            String gcmId = GlobalPreference.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getGCMRegistrationId();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(gcmId)){
                stopSelf();
                return;
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
                    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }, INTERVAL);
        }
    }

    private void getGCMID() {
        try{
            if(mGoogleCloudMessaging == null){
                mGoogleCloudMessaging = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            }
            mRegisterationId = mGoogleCloudMessaging.register(SENDER_ID);
            GlobalPreference.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setGCMRegistrationId(mRegisterationId);
        }
        catch (IOException err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```